# Regex captures commented rows, but nothing when try to remove commented rows

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to re-use a regex I'm using to parse another file.  This file has some commented rows, and I need to make sure the commented rows aren't captured.

This is the string being parsed:

```
m_dwErrorCode = 0; 
m_dwOutError = HOP_OK;  
m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;  
_stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T(""));
if (0x00000000 & value)
{
    
    m_dwErrorCode = 0x0;
    /* Ready state. */
    // m_StatusStr = " Ready(eSTATUS_READY)";
}
if (0x00000001 & value)
{
    m_bProceeding = true;
    /* proceed */
    //m_StatusStr = " Proceeding(eSTATUS)";
}
if (0x00002000 & value)
{
    m_bEmpty = true;
    // We only want to check this error only at certain times.
    if (m_bCheckEmpty)
    {
        if ((m_Attributes.dwMediaID == CUBE1) ||
            (m_Attributes.dwMediaID == CUBE2) ||
            /*(m_Attributes.dwMediaID == SCALLOPED) ||*/ // Added
            (m_Attributes.dwMediaID == FOLDED))
        {

            m_dwErrorCode = 0x00002000;
            _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x1000 - %s(MP Tray Empty)"), errorStr);
            m_dwOutError = HOP_TRAY_EMPTY;
            m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
        }
    }
    //HOP_TRAY_EMPTY
    ///* MSI empty. */
    //m_bTrayEmpty = true;
    //// m_StatusStr = " MSI empty(eSTATUS_MSI_EMPTY)";
}
if (0x00004000 & value)
{
    /* empty. */
    m_dwErrorCode = 0x4000;
    _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x4000 - %s(Tray 1 empty)"), errorStr);
    m_dwOutError = HOP_TRAY_01_EMPTY;
    m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
}
if (0x00008000 & value)
{
    /* Tray 2 empty. */
    m_dwErrorCode = 0x8000;
    _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x8000 - %s(Tray 2 empty)"), errorStr);
    m_dwOutError = HOP_TRAY_02_EMPTY;
    m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
}
if (0x00010000 & value)
{
    /* Tray 3 empty. */
    m_dwErrorCode = 0x10000;
    _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x10000 - %s(Tray 3 empty)"), errorStr);
    m_dwOutError = HOP_TRAY_03_EMPTY;
    m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
}
```

This is the code that gets it mostly right, except it captures the commented rows:

```
Function Get-CaseContents3240{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param ( [string]$parsedCaseMethod)
    Process
    {
 # construct regex
       $fullregex = [regex]"_stprintf[\s\S]*?_T\D*", # Start of error message, capture until digits       
      "(?<sdkErr>[x\d]+)",       # Error number, digits only with x
      "\D[\s\S]*?",           # match anything, non-greedy
      "(?<sdkDesc>\((.+?)\))", # Error description, anything within parentheses, non-greedy
      "([\s\S]*?OutError\s*=(?<sdkOutErr>\s[a-zA-Z_0-9]*))", # Capture OutErr string 
      "[\s\S]*?",             # match anything, non-greedy
      "(?<sdkSeverity>OutSeverity\s*=\s[a-zA-Z_]*)", # Capture severity string and parse out part after underscore later
      '' -join ''
      
      # run the regex on the method contents
      $Values = $parsedCaseMethod | Select-String -Pattern $fullregex -AllMatches
  
      # Convert Name-Value pairs to object properties
      $result = foreach ($match in $Values.Matches){
        [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
          sdkErr      = $($match.Groups['sdkErr'])
          sdkDesc     = $($match.Groups['sdkDesc'])
          sdkOutErr   = $($match.Groups['sdkOutErr'])
          sdkSeverity = ($match.Groups['sdkSeverity'] -split '_')[-1] #take part after _
        }
      }
  
      #add in content that doesn't fall in pattern###################


      #Write-Host "result:" $result -ForegroundColor Green
      #$result;
      return $result
       
    }#End of Process
  }#End of Function
```

This is what the results look like:

```
[Object[17]]
[0]:@{sdkErr=0x; sdkDesc=(tmpStr);sdkOutErr=HOP_OK;sdkSeverity=INFORMATION}
...
```

As you can see, the first one is picking up the commented out lines.

I tried doing this with the first regex line to fix it, but when I do that, the result set is empty:

```
^[\s]+_stprintf[\s\S]*?_T\D*
```

This is the expected results:

```
sdkErr=0x1000                         ###missed this before
sdkDesc=MP Tray Empty
sdkOutErr=HOP_TRAY_EMPTY
sdkSeverity=INFORMATION

sdkErr=0x4000 
sdkDesc=Tray 1 empty
sdkOutErr=HOP_TRAY_01_EMPTY
sdkSeverity=INFORMATION

sdkErr=0x8000
sdkDesc=Tray 2 empty
sdkOutErr=HOP_TRAY_02_EMPTY
sdkSeverity=INFORMATION

sdkErr=0x10000
sdkDesc=Tray 3 empty
sdkOutErr=HOP_TRAY_03_EMPTY
sdkSeverity=INFORMATION
...
```

This is with PowerShell 5.1 and VS Code.

Update:

I'd like to keep the same data structure returned, just so everything is the same after the Function as what I have for other devices.

Update2:

I'm adding this in for input text, just because it seems to make a difference.  Maybe it's the blank line? Or the else? When I copy the _stprintf in regex101 it finds all the sprintf lines/info for the code.

```
    else
    if (0x00200000 & value)
    {
        /* empty */
        m_dwErrorCode = 0x200000;
        _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x200000 - %s(empty)"), errorStr);
        m_dwOutError = HOP_DL_EMPTY;   // Todo: 
        m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
    }
    if (0x00400000 & value)
    {

        /* media size error. */
        m_dwErrorCode = 0x400000;
        _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x400000 - %s(Check Operator Panel)"), errorStr);
        m_dwOutError = HOP_CONTROL_PANEL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED;
        m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
    }
```

Comment: Pretty fragile stuff. I realize it's probably out of the question, but refactoring the source so the SDK error bit is a function or macro would enable you to extract these details in a much more straightforward way that's not so prone to breaking in the future if a dev adds something slightly deviating from the usual pattern. (It would also improve the base code itself, by allowing you to not repeat things like `0x10000` multiple times, with the risk of getting it wrong. Is `"0x1000 - %s(MP Tray Empty)"` really correct giving that we're testing for `0x2000`, for instance?)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I can't do anything with the source.  It's not my team/code, it would require a budget and wouldn't make money, and I'm really just using very old code that never changes to extract a reference document.

Comment: Fair enough. You may consider running this code through your local C or C++ preprocessor (whichever is correct, I'm assuming C); those typically strip out comments before producing the final code (or have an option for doing so). That would free you from the responsibility to do that bit of the parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more maintainable to break it down into individual "if" blocks with one regex, and then parse each block in a second pass...

```
$code = Get-Content "myfile.c" -Raw;

# split into separate "if" blocks.
# (the funky "(?=...)" preserves the delimiter)
$blocks = $code -split "(?=if \(.* \& value\))";
# e.g.
# if (0x00004000 & value)
# {
#     /* empty. */
#     m_dwErrorCode = 0x4000;
#     _stprintf(m_OutDevStr, _T("0x4000 - %s(Tray 1 empty)"), errorStr);
#     m_dwOutError = HOP_TRAY_01_EMPTY;
#     m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
# }

$pattern = `
    "_stprintf[\s\S]*?_T\D*" +
    "(?<sdkErr>[x\d]+)" +
    "\D[\s\S]*?" +
    "\((?<sdkDesc>(.+?))\)" +
    "[\s\S]*?" +
    "(OutError\s*=\s*(?<sdkOutErr>[a-zA-Z_0-9]*))" +
    "[\s\S]*?" +
    "(?<sdkSeverity>OutSeverity\s*=\s[a-zA-Z_]*)";

# note - skip first block as it's the preamble before the first "if"
$blocks `
    | select-object -skip 1 `
    | select-string -pattern $pattern `
    | foreach-object {
         $match = $_.Matches[0];
         [PSCustomObject] [ordered] @{
              "sdkErr"      = $match.Groups['sdkErr']
              "sdkDesc"     = $match.Groups['sdkDesc']
              "sdkOutErr"   = $match.Groups['sdkOutErr']
              "sdkSeverity" = ($match.Groups['sdkSeverity'] -split '_')[-1]
        }
    };
```

Output is:

```
sdkErr  sdkDesc       sdkOutErr         sdkSeverity
------  -------       ---------         -----------
0x1000  MP Tray Empty HOP_TRAY_EMPTY    INFORMATION
0x4000  Tray 1 empty  HOP_TRAY_01_EMPTY INFORMATION
0x8000  Tray 2 empty  HOP_TRAY_02_EMPTY INFORMATION
0x10000 Tray 3 empty  HOP_TRAY_03_EMPTY INFORMATION
```

Comment: this works for all groups.  Very cool.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the pattern to work when the lines are out of order.  I have a case where the order of lines varies from the example.  ...
m_dwOutError = HOP_BUSY;
m_OutSeverity = CCC_INFORMATION;
_stprintf( m_OutDevStr, _T( "1500 - %s (Deviceis busy(Mutex))" ), errorStr);
m_bRestart = FALSE;

Answer (score 1):

Not a robust solution, *it does work* for the code currently posted but I do not assure this will work with the actual code you might test it on.

The regex expects a single string, hence, when testing this with your file, make sure you're using the `-Raw` switch.

See https://regex101.com/r/l0RLPw/2 for details.

```
$re = [regex]@'
(?xsi)
    _stprintf\([\w_,\s]+\("(?<code>\dx\d+)\s*
    -.*?\((?<description>[\w\s]+)\)"\).*?;\s*
    m_dwOutError\s*=\s*(?<error>[\w_]+);\s*
    m_OutSeverity\s*=\s*\w*?_(?<severity>\w+)
'@

$content = Get-Content path/to/content.ext -Raw

foreach($match in $re.Matches($content)) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        sdkErr      = $match.Groups['code']
        sdkDesc     = $match.Groups['description']
        sdkOutErr   = $match.Groups['error']
        sdkSeverity = $match.Groups['severity']
    }
}
```

Result looks like this for me:

```
sdkErr  sdkDesc       sdkOutErr         sdkSeverity
------  -------       ---------         -----------
0x1000  MP Tray Empty HOP_TRAY_EMPTY    INFORMATION
0x4000  Tray 1 empty  HOP_TRAY_01_EMPTY INFORMATION
0x8000  Tray 2 empty  HOP_TRAY_02_EMPTY INFORMATION
0x10000 Tray 3 empty  HOP_TRAY_03_EMPTY INFORMATION
```

Comment: I think the error code comes from the ```_stprintf``` text, not the ```if``` expression - in the case of the ```if (0x00002000 & value)``` block, the error text is ```_T("0x1000 - %s(MP Tray Empty)")``` :-)

Comment: @mclayton oh god lol thank you, didn't noticed

Comment: What is the (?xsi) part?  Also, for one part of the $content I have what I added to Update2, and it's not picking it up, maybe because of the blank line?  Any ideas? Also, why did you put @' around the regex? My old one was just a regex string.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Sorry it took me a couple days to see your responses!

Comment: @Michele `(?xsi)` are the regex flags used. `x`: extended. Spaces and text after a # in the pattern are ignored. `s`: single line. Dot matches newline characters. `i`: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I think I'm going to accept the other answer just because it gets those missing groups I added to Update2.  Thank you so much for helping!!!  I really appreciate it.  :)